# excel - Combine VLOOKUP with Datevalue function

Tags: excel, vlookup

Is it possible to use the DATEVALUE function inside a vlookup?

I am trying to lookup a date in a separate sheet but the date is formatted as string so I'd like to use the DATEVALUE function to convert it.

I have played around with putting the datevalue in a few different positions within the vlookup but no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Put the date in a separate cell such as A1and then call it into the vlookup like so vlookup(A1,range, target column, match type). Then make sure the format for A1 matches the source data, also make sure the indexing column is the leftmost column.

Comment: You cannot use DATEVALUE or anything else within VLOOKUP to convert the lookup range to values. You must - as @SolarMike suggests - edit the data source by using DATEVALUE or VALUE (if dates are formatted in a way Excel would recognize them as a date although they are strings). If Excel cannot recognize them then you need to parse the string.

Comment: @M.Sqrl I beg to differ - kindly see soln below.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9gZE9ZnfA22kt-B3qvg?e=kxMZN8)/screenshot(s) refer -

**Of course you can**- you just need to know how vlookup works and manipulate accordingly - I provide the solution you have specifically requested, together with 2 other possible ways of looking up without 'parsing to date format' in first instance:

---

**Revision** *: see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) for how to input array formula for different versions of Excel - these are otherwise valid for both 2010/Office 365 compatible version of Excel.*

**1] Vlookup**

```
=VLOOKUP(G4,IFERROR(DATEVALUE(C4:D6),D4:D6),2,0)
```

*Unlike other lookup functions (e.g. M2-M3, offset etc.) vlookup cannot be used as a reference itself - it requires the entire range to be included and then 'pivots' on the first column.  This is why you can lookup datevalue of the single column which contains valid text formatted dates, but once you reference a larger range, datevalue(larger range) will return errors for any value in that range which cannot be converted to a date. Hence the iferror component.*

[image: M1 - vlookup + iferror(datevalue,)]

---

I suspect the fundamental goal is to return the cell corresponding to the datevalue of the text you're looking up - you couldn't be fussed whether it's a vlookup or any other form of lookup.  Here are two other methods to achieve this objective:

**2] Sum**

```
=SUM(1*(DATEVALUE(C4:C6)=G4)*(D4:D6))
```

[image: M2 - Sum as a lookup function]

*(Uncommon, albeit parsimonious lookup tool)*

---

**3] Index**

```
=INDEX(D4:D6,MATCH(G4,DATEVALUE(C4:C6),0))
```

[image: Index]

---

**Closing remarks**

*Index is typically preferable to vlookup, given the advantage of being able to be used as a reference itself (e.g. you could have `offset(index<>)` but not `offset(vlookup<>))` - this is why index can lookup columns to the left/right of the lookup column (vlookup works to the right only).  The only advantage `vlookup()` has is the approximate search function (final parameter = True to enable).  `Xlookup()` is more versatile; `offset()` is another 'special / honorary' mention which I have not provided examples for - but also feasible (albeit the latter is has negative stigma associated due to its volatile nature - but that's for another post!)*

---

Comment: I like your VLOOKUP/IFERROR combination. Clever. You should clarify that Shift+Ctrl+Enter is required...

Comment: Ta.  RE: ctrl+shift+enter - yep, will (with caveat this doesn't apply for Office 365 compable verison Excel)

Comment: Interesting. Just tried it on my O365 desktop version and you are correct. I don't have lifetime 2022 version, do you know if you need Shift+Ctrl+Enter on lifetime 2022?

Comment: Hi - I'm confused - you don't have 'lifetime 2022' (not sure which version this is but hey - must be new one that's come out this year I gather) - but you still want to know whether it will work in lifetime? No I don't know off hand - but if I had to guess, if this is more recent release than Office 365 then would be surprised if they remove it.  Note - a lot of folk aren't aware that by simply registering as Office Insider (from file, account, etc.) you could / usaully are eligable for Office 365 or later versions (as/when avail) for free - I was using Office 365 a year before it was released

Comment: There doesn't see to be much info/news regarding 'lifetime 2022' - so either jokes gone over my head or on of us has misread -- you must be referring to Office 365 (unless I made typo and spelt it this way )-- either way - would rather get to other Q - so let me know -- you can easily find out by typing in formula - but would need to visit/review product descriptions to confirm functionality - good summary https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel. Yikes I remember Macintosh (not that old, only started professionally when '93 launched, not to give my age away lol).. keep safe, ta J